# VSTO SSO Office Interop Auth Library

Tags: .net, excel, single-sign-on, vsto, office-addins

Is there any documention on an Office.Interop library that we can use in a .NET VSTO add in that manages/interacts with the SSO User.

There is a Office.js library that allows you to interact with the object here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.auth?view=common-js-preview

I'm trying to see if there is anything mirroring that on the VSTO side.

Searching through the object models. Couldn't find anything

Comment: What Office application is your VSTO addin running in?

Comment: The tag used for the post answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

VSTO (nor Office) doesn't provide anything for that. You may consider use third-party providers for using SSO in your VSTO add-in.